# How do I delete a '_' prefix on a variable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I have a variable that reads as _123456 and I need to delete the underscore prefix on this variable before storing it to a field.  How do I do this?

```
 var value = "_123456"
```

Comment: There is more on this world than jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`value.substr(1)`

No need for jQuery!

Comment: This is also good!, actually I like this method better than the regex method...seems less processor intensive...am I right?

Comment: Your question made me think you where asking for all of the ways to achieve your goal rather than what is the preferred way.

Answer (score 5):

This is just generic Javascript, not specific to jQuery. You'd do something like this:

> var result = value.substring(1);

Or...

> var result = value.replace(/^_/, '');

Or... (if there can be more than one underscore)

> var result = value.replace(/^_+/, '');

Comment: or `"_123456".substr(1)` or `"_123456".slice(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = "_123456"
var trimmed = value.substring(1); // "123456"
```

Comment: `value.substr(1)` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

[not recommended]
To do this with jQuery (and an if):

```
var element = $('<div></div>'); 
var text = "_123456"; 
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { 
   if ( i > 0 ) {
      element.append('<span>' + text[i] + '</span>'); 
   }
}
var trimmed = element.text();
```

I tried `element.remove(':first')` instead of the `if`, but it didn't seem to work. No idea why.

Comment: way more work than I'm willing to put forth for this small of an issue...this solution is just too long... value.substring(1) is all I needed....

Comment: Sure, but u asked for jQuery and I thought it was fun to try :) Please note the "not recommended". I wouldn't do it this way neither.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - If the underscore is after the digits then you could use `parseInt()`

```
var value = "123456_"
```

So for example `parseInt("123456_")` will return the number 123456.